# QVariant alternative when migrating from PyQt5 to PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I am having some trouble switching from PyQt5 to PySide2 because of the following piece of code:

```
class EnumModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, list_of_enums):
        """
        Enumeration model
        :param list_of_enums: list of enumeration values to show
        """
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = list_of_enums

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid() is True:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return QtCore.QVariant(self.items[index.row()].value[0])
            elif role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole:
                return QtCore.QVariant(self.items[index.row()].value[0])
        return QtCore.QVariant()
```

The code woks fine under PyQt5.

In my efforts on migrating I found that [the official website](https://wiki.qt.io/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt) says:

> PySide only supports PyQt's API 2 (see PSEP 101) for details.
>   Therefore Qt classes such as QStrings, QStringLists, and QVariants are
>   not available on PySide. Instead, you should simply use native Python
>   datatypes.

So the solution would be (I guess) to simply change `QVariant` by `str`. When I do that the class does not throw any error, but it does not display the model either.

In fact the function `data` is receiving `role=13` instead of `role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole`.

I don't know if this is a bug with PySide2 (which under Linux is a bit buggy) or it is because of something else.

An minimum viable example is this:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2 import QtCore
from enum import Enum


class SomeEnum(Enum):
    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
    C = 'C'


class EnumModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, list_of_enums):
        """
        Enumeration model
        :param list_of_enums: list of enumeration values to show
        """
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.items = list_of_enums

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid() is True:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self.items[index.row()].value[0]
            elif role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole:
                return self.items[index.row()].value[0]
            else:
                print('not recognised')
        return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    model = EnumModel([SomeEnum.A, SomeEnum.A, SomeEnum.B, SomeEnum.C])

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    lst = QListView()
    lst.setModel(model)
    lst.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is the value of `list_of_enums`?, provide a [mcve].  I have tested your code by changing `QtCore.QVariant(self.items[index.row()].value[0])` to `self.items[index.row()]` , passing `list_of_enums = ["a", "b", "c"]` and it works correctly so I think the error is in `list_of_enums`.

Comment: If you're not going to explicitly return a value, you should call the base-class `data` method instead. The `role=13` is `SizeHintRole`, so what value are you returning for that?

Comment: Hi, So I made a complete example. Under ubuntu 18.04, PySide2 5.12.3 it does not show anything on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when the view requires information related to the role `Qt::SizeHintRole` (13) you are passing it an empty string, instead you must return None or simply do not return anything since it interferes with the other roles:

```py
def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    if index.isValid():
        print(role)
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.items[index.row()].value[0]
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole:
            return self.items[index.row()].value[0]
        else:
            print('not recognised')
```